# Tkinter Serial data on multiple pages

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using Python3 with TKinter and have run into an issue, even after reading the forums and the TKdocs website I am still making no headway. I am receiving temperature readings via my com-port. My program so far has a Start page and a page one with a graph on it that updates with every reading. So the question is how can I print the sensor data on page one as well, I am new to tkinter.

I will post the code below any advice welcome.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import random
import sys
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #import matplotlib library
from drawnow import *
import urllib
import json
import serial # import Serial Library
import numpy  # Import numpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
style.use("ggplot") #ggplot...dark_background

do = []
tempF= []

f = Figure(figsize=(10,6), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)

arduinoData = serial.Serial('com3', 115200) #Creating our serial object 



def animate(i):

  if(arduinoData.inWaiting()>0):

#read serial data
arduinoString = arduinoData.readline()
xList = []
yList = []



#Parse serial data
arduinoString.split()
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
words = arduinoString.split()

reading = words[3]

if words[1] == (b'TEMP') :
    print (words[0])
    print (words[1])
    print (words[3])
    tempF.append(reading)                  #Build our tempF array by appending temp readings

a.clear()
a.plot(*yList, *yList)   


title = "    D.O : "+str(do) + "\n Temp : " + str(tempF)
a.set_title(title)




arduinoData.flushInput()
arduinoData.flushOutput()




class Application(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Stylibleue Dashboard")


    # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames on top each other
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    #Switch through pages
    self.frames = {}

    for F in (StartPage, Page1,):

        frame = F(container, self)

        self.frames[F] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(StartPage)

def show_frame(self, cont):

    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()



class StartPage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    #Page Labels
    label = tk.Label(self, text=("""     D.O : 
    """), font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(row=100, column=20, sticky="nsew")

    label = tk.Label(self, text=("""<Sensor reading here>
    """), font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(row=100, column=30, sticky="nsew")

    label = tk.Label(self, text=(""" TEMP : 
    """), font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(row=100, column=40, sticky="nsew")

    label = tk.Label(self, text=("""<Sensor reading here>        
    """), font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.grid(row=100, column=50, sticky="nsew") 


    #Go to Page1 button
    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page1",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))
    button1.grid(row=100, column=60, sticky="nsew")



class Page1(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Bassin 2!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    #Return home button
    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.pack()


    #This is the embedded matplotlib graph
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)




app = Application()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=1000)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I misunderstood the question, so now I am rewriting the answer. If you still have some doubts or this is not what you were expecting, just comment below. I'll try my best to help. Also, I don't have an arduino to check this for.

I have made the following changes to your code:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #Page Labels
        label = tk.Label(self, text=("""     D.O : 
        """), font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row=100, column=20, sticky="nsew")

        label = tk.Label(self, text=("""<Sensor reading here>
        """), font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row=100, column=30, sticky="nsew")

        label = tk.Label(self, text=(""" TEMP : 
        """), font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row=100, column=40, sticky="nsew")

        label = tk.Label(self, text=("""<Sensor reading here>        
        """), font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row=100, column=50, sticky="nsew") 

        # Reading data from the arduino

        def DataRead():
            msg = arduinoData.read(arduinoData.inWaiting()) # read everything in the input buffer
            print ("Message from arduino: ")
            print (msg)

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Print arduino data",
                            command=lambda: DataRead())
        button1.grid()

        #Go to Page1 button
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))
        button1.grid(row=100, column=60, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply, I will try both these concepts out and let you know how I get on. Cheers.

Comment: Hi I'm trying to Send the data to page1 as an argument but cant get it working. My sensor reading  is not in startpage as your code states, it comes from a define statement outside of any class (at the top of my code). Still stuck

Comment: Oh. I found the question a little unclear. Anyway, define the function "animate", inside the "__init__" of "page1" (one that you have made outside). Then make a button on "page1" to run "animate". This should solve it. Let me know if this works, or if you need help. I will change my answer.

Comment: Well, no luck so far. Not through lack of trying tho. Could you show me how this would be adapted for my code? with the measurement not in any class. Thanks. Leon

Comment: Hi I still am not getting this. I would be willing to pay if someone could show me how to implement this it's really the crucial part for my whole project.

Comment: So, you want to print the sensor data from "arduinodata" to print on your screen? Do you want to do anything else?

Comment: No just that. I have the graph updating on "page1" already but I have not managed to print that data on the start page. Thanks for your patience and advice by the way.